# i can't write java code in my page jsp why?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

Good evening I have a big problem that I do not know how to solve, my problem is that I want to write my java code in my page jsp so I use the scriptlets <%%> but when I want to write on it nothing works example if I want to put a String I put S and I click on ctrl + space so that it completes me the word String but no it does not recognize same thing for connection, resultset ... I tried to write them manually but when I execute it shows me an error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
```

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/Acceuil_proprietaire.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Connection`enter code here`
  location: class org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Acceuil_005fproprietaire_jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : Acceuil_proprietaire
    Created on : 3 oct. 2019, 20:13:00
    Author     : hp
--%>
<%@page import="controller.Cnx"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%
Connection c=Cnx.getcnx();
%>


<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Gestion parkings</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Sufee Admin - HTML5 Admin Template">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/themify-icons/css/themify-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/selectFX/css/cs-skin-elastic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ccs_accueil_proprietaire.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3fd0d5f24.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
<%
          String msg=(String) request.getAttribute("msg");
          if(msg!=null && !msg.equals("") ){
 %>  
          <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
         $("#myModal").modal('toggle');

    });        


          </script>

          <% } %>



    <!-- Left Panel -->

    <aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-default" style="flex-flow:column wrap;">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gestion parkings</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand hidden" href="./"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Logo"></a>
            </div>

            <div id="main-menu" class="main-menu collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" style="margin-right: 20px;" selected></i>Gestion locaux</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>Places</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>Contrats</a>

                    </li>



                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </aside>

    <nav class="navbar" style="height:70px;" id='nav-proprietaire'>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a href="Page_de_cnx" class="nav-link"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding-left: 1470px; text-transform: uppercase"> <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>Déconnection</a>

                    </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  <div id='divformproprietaire'>  
      <form method="POST" action='Gestion_des_locaux'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class='labelproprietaire'>Nom du local :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomlocal" id="nomlocal" aria-describedby="nomlocalHelp" placeholder="Enter the name of local">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class='labelproprietaire'>Nom proprietaire :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomproprietaire" placeholder="Entrer votre nom" name="nomproprietaire">
  `enter code here`</div>
  `enter code here`<div class="form-group">
      `enter code here`<label class='labelproprietaire'>Adresse du local :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adresselocal" placeholder="Entrer l'adresse du local" name="adresselocal">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class='labelproprietaire'>Nombre de place disponible :</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbrplacedispo" placeholder="Entrer le nombre de place disponible dans le local" name="nbrplace">

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label class='labelproprietaire'>Superficie :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Superficielocal" placeholder="Entrer la superficie du local" name="superficielocal">

  </div>
  <div id='divbtnaddlocal'>      
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='btnajouterlocal' style='vertical-align: 0;' name='action' value='ajouter'><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>Ajouter</button>
  </div>
    </form>
  </div>

    <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-active">
      <th scope="col">Nom local</th>
      <th scope="col">Nom proprietaire</th>
      <th scope="col">Adresse local</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre de place</th>
      <th scope="col">Superficie</th>



    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>



       <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

      </tr>





  </tbody>
</table> 

    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Information</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        ${msg}
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <!-- /#left-panel -->

    <!-- Left Panel -->

    <!-- Right Panel -->





    <!-- Right Panel -->

    <script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


    <script src="vendors/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($) {
            "use strict";

            jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
                map: 'world_en',
                backgroundColor: null,
                color: '#ffffff',
                hoverOpacity: 0.7,
                selectedColor: '#1de9b6',
                enableZoom: true,
                showTooltip: true,
                values: sample_data,
                scaleColors: ['#1de9b6', '#03a9f5'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "it shows me an error." What's the error? Also, what IDE or editor are you using?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDE cannot autocomplete "Connection" because you didn't import the `Connection` class to your JSP file.

You need to add an import statement for `Connection` like so:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
```

Alternatively, you can be a bit lazy and just import the entire `java.sql` package:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
```

Once you set up your file properly, your IDE should be able to autocomplete properly.